# Simplification assumptions strange behavior

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to cancel common factors under square roots in some expression with all positive real variables:
$$\text{Simplify}\left[\frac{\left(3+\sqrt{6}\right) \sqrt{g} \text{nn}^4}{2 \sqrt{\text{nn}^7 P*T}},\text{nn}>0\land P>0\land T>0\right]$$

which returns the same thing
$$\frac{\left(3+\sqrt{6}\right) \sqrt{g} \text{nn}^4}{2 \sqrt{\text{nn}^7 P T}}.$$

However, removing the assumptions for $P,T$ makes it work: 
$$\text{Simplify}\left[\frac{\left(3+\sqrt{6}\right) \sqrt{g} \text{nn}^4}{2 \sqrt{\text{nn}^7 P T}},\text{nn}>0\right]$$
$$\frac{\left(3+\sqrt{6}\right) \sqrt{g \text{nn}}}{2 \sqrt{P T}}.$$

Why does it happen? And a more important question, what is a better way to cancel common factors under roots with positive real variables in the more general case with larger expressions and many variables to cancel, so that I am sure no common factors remain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the function `PowerExpand`?

```
PowerExpand[((3 + Sqrt[6]) nn^4 Sqrt[g])/(2 Sqrt[nn^7 P*T])]

(*   ((3+Sqrt[6]) Sqrt[g] Sqrt[nn])/(2 Sqrt[P] Sqrt[T])  *)
```

Comment: Good! It does the job.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I turn the simplifications into a list:

```
{nn>0,P>0,T>0}.
```

Comment: Simplify[((3 + Sqrt[6]) nn^4 Sqrt[g])/(
 2 Sqrt[nn^7 P*T]), {nn > 0, P > 0, T > 0}] still gives the same result for me. I am using Mathematica 10.0.0.0

Comment: Odd.  What about using Refine instead of Simplify?  Both work for me.

Comment: Refine[...,{nn > 0, P > 0, T > 0}] works nicely. So, finally I need to do either Simplify[Refine[...,assumptions]], or Simplify[PowerExpand[...],assumption]